# Odoo sending context to many2many popup form

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8

I have a custom object (x_items) and it's linked to the project task (project.task) as many2many field.

In the form view of the task the field is appearing as table with an option in the footer (add an item).

Once i click on add an item a pop up form open.

What i need is to send variables using context from the task to the popup window..

So any idea how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you already tried this?

```
<field name="x_items" context="{write your context here!}"/>
```

Comment: it worked but on the save i am getting a problem (ProgrammingError: ARRAY types integer and boolean cannot be matched
) Full Logs here: https://justpaste.it/rvtn

Comment: this shouldn't have nothing to do with passing the context, but it is probably some other bug in your code.

Comment: If you need help with that, try to create a new question specifically for this new problem.

Answer (score 0):

ProgrammingError: ARRAY types integer and boolean cannot be matched.

This type of error raised when you give widget many2many_tags to Many2one field.So check your field and widget that you gave.

Answer (score 0):

```
context = {'default_item_ids': self.item_ids and [(6,0, self.item_ids.ids)] or []}
```

this should work